# How do I aggregate multiple rows in one in pandas without using a function like sum?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to aggregate multiple rows in a dataset. However, the usual functions I found on the net are "sum()" and "mean()".

I have How can I aggregate multiple rows:

```
Movie | Comedy | Horror | Drama
A         1        0        0
A         0        0        1    
B         0        1        0
B         0        0        1
```

to

```
Movie | Comedy | Horror | Drama
A         1        0        1
B         0        1        1
```

Comment: It's not clear why you don't want to use `sum` here. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Movie', as_index=False).sum()
```

output:

```
Movie   Comedy  Horror  Drama           
   A      1       0       1
   B      0       1       1
```

Comment: can also add index=False to avoid setting 'Movie' as index